# Prove that if polynomial with integral coefficients has a solution in integers, then the congruence is solvable for any value of modulus $m$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, modular-arithmetic

> Prove that if $F(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n) = 0$, where $F$ is a polynomial with integral coefficients, has a solution in integers, then the congruence $F(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n) \equiv 0 \pmod{m}$ is solvable for any value of modulus $m$.

I am not sure how to prove this.

**My attempt:**
Let $F(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n) = \sum_{i_1, i_2, \ldots, i_n} a_{i_1, i_2, \ldots, i_n} x_1^{i_1} x_2^{i_2} \ldots x_n^{i_n}$ be the polynomial with integer coefficients. Suppose there exists a solution $(a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n)$ such that $F(a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n) = 0$.

Consider the congruences:

$ x_1 \equiv a_1 \pmod{m} $

$ x_2 \equiv a_2 \pmod{m} $

$ \vdots $

$ x_n \equiv a_n \pmod{m} $

By the definition of congruence, we have $x_i = a_i + m \cdot t_i$ for some integers $t_i$.
Substitute these expressions into $F(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)$:

$$ F(a_1 + m \cdot t_1, a_2 + m \cdot t_2, \ldots, a_n + m \cdot t_n) = 0 $$
Is this correct so far? Not sure what to do next.

Comment: Question is already closed, no need to be mean to nominate it for deletion. We all start from somewhere and there might be some people whom it may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just say $F(x_1,\ldots, x_n) = 0$ $\implies$ $F(x_1, \ldots, x_n) \equiv_m 0$ $\forall m \in \mathbb{N}$, as $0 \equiv_m 0$ for all such $m$?

Comment: It makes sense, thanks. maybe the problem wasn't as hard as i initially thought. Btw I am wondering is it possible to show something useful with my attempt or is it already doomed to fail?

Comment: You CAN show that if $F(x_1,\ldots, x_n) = 0$ then $F(y_1, \ldots, y_n) \equiv_m 0$ for all $y_1,\ldots, y_n$ such that $y_i \equiv_m x_i$.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs. This is enforced site policy, see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).